# Iteratively replace every cell in a dataframe using values from the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a sample dataframe:
[image: example dataframe to update]

I need to be able to get "2023-01-01" *edit: (a string of random numbers, not a true Date object)* and "Python is awesome", and send it through a function(`do_calculations(date, phrase)`), which will return a new value, which will be put in place where "Python is awesome" used to be.
Then I will send "2023-01-01" and "Is the pizza" through a function and the new returned value will be put in place of "Is the pizza". Finally, I will get "2023-01-01" and "Pizza" and do the same.

I will then go down the column and do the same with "2023-01-02", followed by "2023-01-03", and so forth, until all the cells are replaced.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
for i, row in new_df.iterrows():
    print('index: ', i)
    print('row: ', row['Date'], row['Title1'], row.index)
    if row['Title1']:
        text = do_calculations(row['Date'], row['Title1'][0])
        #print("TEXT:", text)
        value = new_df.at[i, row.index[1]]
        print("VALUE:", value)
        
        new_df.at[i, row.index[2]] = text
```

But cannot get it working. I imagine there's another for loop required in there, and better use of the `i` index.

Whether a new dataframe is made, or the dataframe is updated in-place, does not matter - whichever is faster would be preferred.

---

Here is code to generate the sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import datetime

# Create a list of dates
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023', end='1/10/2023', freq='D')

# Generate random phrases
phrases = ['Hello world', 'Python is awesome', None, 'Data science is fun', 'I love coding', 'Pandas is powerful', 'Pineapples', 'Pizza', 'Krusty', 'krab', 'Is the pizza']

# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'title1', 'title2', 'title3'])

# Populate DataFrame with random phrases
for date in date_rng:
    # Generate random phrases for each column
    row = [date]
    row.extend(random.sample(phrases, 3))
    
    # Append row to DataFrame
    df = df.append(pd.Series(row, index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)

# Print DataFrame
print(df)
```

edit: I've clarified that one of the arguments being passed is a string of numbers, not a true date object, which most of the answers seem to be accounting for.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do following with two loops

```py
for i, row in new_df.iterrows():
    for col in ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']:
        if row[col]:
            text = do_calculations(row['Date'], row[col])
            new_df.loc[i, col] = text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's way to do what you've asked by calling the function cell-by-cell using apply:

```python
df[df.columns[1:]] = (
    df.apply(lambda row: [do_calculations(row.Date.date(), val) 
    for val in row[1:]], axis=1, result_type='expand') )
```

Sample function:

```python
callnum = [0]
def do_calculations(date, phrase):
    callnum[0] += 1
    return f'{phrase} {date} {callnum[0]}'
```

Output:

```
                  Date                            title1                          title2                             title3
0  2023-01-01 00:00:00               Krusty 2023-01-01 1      I love coding 2023-01-01 2    Pandas is powerful 2023-01-01 3
1  2023-01-02 00:00:00                 krab 2023-01-02 4  Python is awesome 2023-01-02 5   Data science is fun 2023-01-02 6
2  2023-01-03 00:00:00                 None 2023-01-03 7      I love coding 2023-01-03 8                 Pizza 2023-01-03 9
3  2023-01-04 00:00:00   Python is awesome 2023-01-04 10        Pineapples 2023-01-04 11                 krab 2023-01-04 12
4  2023-01-05 00:00:00       I love coding 2023-01-05 13        Pineapples 2023-01-05 14                 krab 2023-01-05 15
5  2023-01-06 00:00:00               Pizza 2023-01-06 16              None 2023-01-06 17               Krusty 2023-01-06 18
6  2023-01-07 00:00:00          Pineapples 2023-01-07 19             Pizza 2023-01-07 20    Python is awesome 2023-01-07 21
7  2023-01-08 00:00:00        Is the pizza 2023-01-08 22        Pineapples 2023-01-08 23                 None 2023-01-08 24
8  2023-01-09 00:00:00  Pandas is powerful 2023-01-09 25             Pizza 2023-01-09 26  Data science is fun 2023-01-09 27
9  2023-01-10 00:00:00  Pandas is powerful 2023-01-10 28              None 2023-01-10 29           Pineapples 2023-01-10 30
```

Alternatively, if your function can date a Series argument for date and for phrase, you can use apply on a column-by-column basis:

```python
df[df.columns[1:]] = ( df[df.columns[1:]]
    .apply(lambda col: vect_calculations(df.Date.infer_objects(), col)) )
```

Sample function:

```python
vect_callnum = [0]
def vect_calculations(date, phrase):
    vect_callnum[0] += 1
    return phrase + ' ' + date.astype(str) + f' {vect_callnum[0]}'
```

Output:

```
                  Date                            title1                            title2                            title3
0  2023-01-01 00:00:00          Hello world 2023-01-01 1               Krusty 2023-01-01 2                 krab 2023-01-01 3
1  2023-01-02 00:00:00         Is the pizza 2023-01-02 1               Krusty 2023-01-02 2                               NaN
2  2023-01-03 00:00:00          Hello world 2023-01-03 1    Python is awesome 2023-01-03 2                 krab 2023-01-03 3
3  2023-01-04 00:00:00           Pineapples 2023-01-04 1               Krusty 2023-01-04 2    Python is awesome 2023-01-04 3
4  2023-01-05 00:00:00          Hello world 2023-01-05 1               Krusty 2023-01-05 2         Is the pizza 2023-01-05 3
5  2023-01-06 00:00:00           Pineapples 2023-01-06 1  Data science is fun 2023-01-06 2    Python is awesome 2023-01-06 3
6  2023-01-07 00:00:00   Pandas is powerful 2023-01-07 1          Hello world 2023-01-07 2                Pizza 2023-01-07 3
7  2023-01-08 00:00:00           Pineapples 2023-01-08 1                               NaN  Data science is fun 2023-01-08 3
8  2023-01-09 00:00:00  Data science is fun 2023-01-09 1                Pizza 2023-01-09 2                               NaN
9  2023-01-10 00:00:00                Pizza 2023-01-10 1         Is the pizza 2023-01-10 2                 krab 2023-01-10 3
```

Note that in the the first solution above, the number of function calls (as indicated by the values of callnum visible in the output df) is equal to the number of cells, whereas in the second solution the function is called only once for each phrase column (as indicated by the values of vect_callnum in the output).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a vectorized approach, a possible solution is:

```
def f(x):
    return x

df.iloc[:,1:] = f(df.iloc[:,1:].values)
```